# SharePoint 2010 Modal dialog problem with Jquery datepicker

Tags: 2010, jquery, jquery-ui

i have a link on which i am opening a webpartpage embed in SharePoint ModalDialog. Inside webpart I have a textbox contains jquery.datepicker ..whenever i select the date the ribbons title scrolls up of dialogbox. I just figured out that if i place the following line in masterpage without the tag scroll="no"

```
<body onload="if (typeof(_spBodyOnLoadWrapper) != 'undefined') _spBodyOnLoadWrapper();" class="v4master" style="background-color: #F6F6F6">
```

I get two scroll bars like this (notice the extreme right) and when i select the date it actually scrolls up the ribbon and i need to go up again using the extreme right vertical scroll bar...but if put scroll="no" tag in box I only get 1 scroll bar the extreme right not the inside one..so when select the date and ribbon gets shifted up a little i cannot go up due to no scroll bar. how to fix this thing..I have fixed width master page design.

without scroll="no" directive in body tag (note two vertical scroll bars at right hand)
[image]

with scroll="no" in body tag (note single scroll bar at right hand)
[image]

here is my JQUERY in webpart.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () { 
   BindEvents(); 
}); 

$(function () { 
   var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance(); 
   prm.add_endRequest(function () { 
   BindEvents(); 
  }); 
}); 

function BindEvents() { 

  var $ = jQuery.noConflict(); 

   $('input[id*="txtftrNeededBy"]').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-M-y', changeMonth: true, minDate: 0 });
   $('input[id*="txtNeededBy"]').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-M-y', changeMonth: true, minDate: 0 });
   $('input[id*="txtftrQty"]').autoNumeric({ aSep: '', vMax: '999999', vMin: '0', wEmpty: 'zero', mDec: null });
   $('input[id*="txtQty"]').autoNumeric({ aSep: '', vMax: '999999', vMin: '0', wEmpty: 'zero', mDec: null });
  } 
</script>
```

Comment: oh i just figured..its working fine in Mozilla firefox but happening weird in IE :(

Comment: Finally figured out the culprit but need assistance here to fix my problem :) see my edited question again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a bug in jquery.ui.datepicker.js ..did the following to eliminate the weird scroll up behaviour.

```
change:

Line 1498: '" href="#">' + printDate.getDate() + '</a>')) + '</td>'; // display selectable date

to:

Line 1498: '" href="javascript:;">' + printDate.getDate() + '</a>')) + '</td>'; // display selectable date
```

Reference url : http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/5981

Answer (score 0):

what version jquery and jquery ui did you use?

Answer (score 0):

Check the page's document type tag to make sure it is set and is set to a valid value.